# WPF Portlet like Layout Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I'd like to design a custom control which can be used as a container like other Layout controls. I want this control to have a dependency property named Header which can display header for this control. Basic intention is to imitate looks of portlet control available in Sharepoint etc. with configurable headers.

Any links, suggestions, code samples to achieve similar functionality is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at basing it off the existing [Expander control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx). This has a Header and a Content and it should be fairly trivial to change the style to remove the expand button.